# Holo theme for AppCompat library

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-support-library, android-holo-everywhere

I have used the ActionBarSherlock+HoloEverywhere combination for a while, and it is working good. However, the time has come to migrate to the official Google AppCompat library.

If I am right, the latest version of HoloEverywhere should work with AppCompat. I can use the AppCompat library easily, but on older devices, it uses the default, non-Holo themes, like it should. When applying the HoloEverywhere project, I am getting `Attribute "_____" has already been defined` errors (102 of them), which points to two different folders, `\res\values\abc_attrs.xml` and `\res\values\attrs.xml` in the HoloEverywhere project.

Is it a known issue, or am I doing something wrong? If yes, how should I do it? For the record, I am using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: _"However, the time has come to migrate to the official Google AppCompat library"_ --- Would you please define this? Why anyone should use AppCompat instead of ABS?

Comment: Since AppCompat is maintained by Google, you will probably recieve updates and fixes, much faster then you would, if you use ABS. At least, this is my thought process.

Comment: Check this: https://github.com/Prototik/HoloEverywhere/issues/570 . In short: ABC is bundled with HE.

Comment: Oh my, never noticed this, I was blindly trying to just replace ABS with ABC. Thanks for the link, if you write it in an answer, I will accept is.

Comment: @hundeva fair enough. If one follows that kind of reasoning, I bet, need for support library (and ABS for that matter) diminishes much earlier than ABS lagging behind in possible future new features...

Comment: Also, no disrespect to Jake Wharton (he did a pretty good job), but the official support of Google is just too much/good to refuse, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @langerhans pointed out, the latest HE contains the ABC, so there is no need to add the ABC library a second time, after deleting it, my issues are solved.